# Regular Expression matching on a specific string, space, then number (pandas, python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

My dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'module_num': ['Assignment Module 6 Due', 'Review of Module 2 Checklist', 'Welcome to Module 7 Chapter 25']})
```

I am new to regular expressions in python and I was hoping I could get the following output using regex and pandas:

```
    pd.DataFrame({'module_num': ['Module 6', 'Module 2', 'Module 7']})
```

So, I am trying to match on the string "Module" and the number that comes after it. There is a white space in between Module and the number in every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract)

[`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/VLs8Vz/1)

```
df.module_num.str.extract("(Module \d+)")
```

---

```
          0
0  Module 6
1  Module 2
2  Module 7
```

Comment: Downvoter, it would be great if could add reason for downvoting rather than just downvoting and leaving people on confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use Named group followed by white space and digit to `.str.extract`

```
df.module_num.str.extract('(?P<module_num>Module\s\d)')



     module_num
    0  Module 6
    1  Module 2
    2  Module 7
```

**How it works**
`(?P<name>group)` captures the named group refered to by name. name must be an alphanumeric sequence starting with a letter.

`\s` is for white space

`\d` special character for digit.